# Is there a $\mathbb{C}_g$, where $g$ is composite?

Tags: number-theory, abstract-algebra, schemes

Analogous to the $p$-adic ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$, you can (at least formally), define the $g$-adic ring $\mathbb{Z}_g$, where $g$ is composite. Of course when completing to a field, you get in trouble because of the zero-divisors:

My questions are:

- Can something be done here to resolve this (i.e. weaken field axioms, take into account the zero divisors, etc).
- Can you speak of objects like $\mathbb{Q}_g$ and $\mathbb{C}_g$, where $g$ is composite ?
- Can you speak of $\mathbb{A}_{Berk,\mathbb{C}_g}^1$ and $\mathbb{P}_{Berk,\mathbb{C}_g}^1$,  where $g$ is composite ?
- Does someone know of research to these objects ?

As vague as ever, I conclude ...

Edit: I found a book "p-adic numbers and their functions" by Kurt Mahler which says something of the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and the ring $\mathbb{Q}_g$. Of course you can't algebraically complete a ring like we normally would, but then the question remains: can you construct something which looks like it (an "algebraic completion" of the ring $\mathbb{Q}_g$, so to speak).

Comment: At least on point one, you can localize around the ideal of zero divisors. That will make every non-zero-divisor invertable. You can't invert more elements, because the moment you have an invertible zero-divisor, the whole ring becomes trivial.

Comment: There is a new book by Jerome Poineau "The Berkovich line over $\mathbb{Z}$" which sounds like it might be relevant to your question. I have no idea what's in it, I just saw it on a shelf once :-)

Comment: In the setting of Mahler's book, ${\mathbf Z}_g$ is the $g$-adic completion of ${\mathbf Z}$ and is isomorphic to ${\mathbf Z}_{p_1} \times \cdots \times {\mathbf Z}_{p_r}$ where $p_1,\dots,p_r$ are the different prime factors of $g$ (their multiplicities don't matter). Thus formally one can just declare ${\mathbf Q}_{g}$ to be the product of the ${\mathbf Q}_{p_i}$'s, likewise with ${\mathbf C}_g$, etc. Whether this leads anywhere nontrivial is a different issue.